# My website suddenly display IOException, Nopcommerce

Tags: c#, asp.net, nopcommerce

I have a website that runs on Nopcommerce platform. I am not familiar with Nopcommerce but I have been assigned to troubleshoot this. I do have experience in ASP.net which would probably helps.

One day, the website just went down displaying the following error in production server as per attached.
What we found out is that when we switch the database to our uat database, it works fine, which we deduct there is probably nothing wrong with the program itself, but the DB. I'm suspecting maybe some data in production DB may have cause error but I still couldn't fully isolate the problem. We tried using a lot of breakpoints and we discover we could not enter the our home .cshtml file after passing through Application_Start()

Edit: These test are done on both the production server and testing server, with both DB on both server.

We compared theme and catalog configuration setting but its similar.
We were also told to delete files in Temporary ASP.NET folder, but that doesn't work either.
DB is SQL Server by the way.

Thanks in advance

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the 
current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.IO.IOException: The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:


[IOException: The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.
]
   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) +12841516
   System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext() +12933561
   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +445
   System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(String path) +91
   System.Web.Compilation.StandardDiskBuildResultCache.FindSatelliteDirectories() +22
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.RegularAppRuntimeModeInitialize() +107
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.Initialize() +251
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InitializeBuildManager() +227
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.HostingInit(HostingEnvironmentFlags hostingFlags, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +475

[HttpException (0x80004005): The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.
]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +10075596
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +95
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +254
```

Comment: Paste the actual exception, we cant search google for that exception if its an image... Also i am super lazy and refuse to type it...

Comment: The `[visual-studio]` tag should only be used for questions pertaining to Visual Studio (the application).

Comment: sorry @MichaelRandall updated the post

Comment: Did you already search for this error on the internet? You will get lots of hits.

Comment: Try to replica the production to Testing server application and db wise, and check it again

Comment: @MohtishamZubair Did that same error. Editted the post

Comment: hmmm check the EventViewer as Administrator user for additional info. And also check user rights on application folder as it is saying file or directory is corrupted or unreadable

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/516706/Theplusfileplusorplusdirectoryplusispluscorruptedp